# Getting Unknown Type error for custom option in Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.4.2

I have added custom option for 'Apply' in Cart price rule. But when trying add product to cart I get following error
**place_x_receive_y_free is unknown type {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): place_x_receive_y_free is unknown type at /app/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/CalculatorFactory.php:51)"}**

place_x_receive_y_free -> this is my custom option i have added in Apply. What is wrong?How can I fix this?

Comment: How you have implement logic on fronted, which plugin or event you used ? share your solution here.
I have facing issue in fronted.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365294/magento-2-how-to-use-custom-options-in-action-apply-field-in-cart-price-rule-fr

Answer (score 0):

you need to properly override Magento sales rules

1. di.xml

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider">
  <plugin name="Yourmodule-salesrule-plugin" type="YourModule\YourFile\Plugin\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CalculatorFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="discountRules" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="place-x-receive-y-free." xsi:type="string">YourModule\YourFile\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\PlaceXReceiveYFree </item>                               
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

2. Events.xml file

   ```
    <!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="salesrule_validator_process">
           <observer name="your_custom_rules" instance="YourModule\YourFile\Observer\PlaceXReceiveYFree" />
       </event>
   </config>
   ```
3. Observerfile PlaceXReceiveYFree.php and then write your logic in this observer file to properly override

Comment: How can implement item qty level discount in fronted. I have try this plugin <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Action\Discount\CalculatorFactory"> but not working. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365294/magento-2-how-to-use-custom-options-in-action-apply-field-in-cart-price-rule-fr

Comment: have you tried printing object from observer file
$address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();
then 
foreach ($address->getAllItems() as $q):
$validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($q);
   if ($validate):
you can write your custom logic with frontend added cart items